# Add custom Intellisense feature to my Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have created a new SP that would simply return top 10 row in descending order like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE giveme
    @TableName NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sqlQuery = '
        SELECT TOP 10 *
        FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WITH (NOLOCK)
        ORDER BY 1 DESC;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery;
END;
```

and while executing the SP does not produce all the table names in the database with the help of Intellisense. Although, when i use:

```
select * from
```

it does show suggestions with table names. How to add table name suggestion to the SP?

Comment: Do you mean performing a partial match of `@TableName` against the table in your database? using `LIKE  + @TableName + '%'`?

Comment: This can't be done, and this really isn't the kind of thing you want as a stored procedure., I personally don't find typing `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM x ORDER BY 1` a big enough inconvenience to warrant any kind of automation, but if you are doing this all the time, you might consider [creating a snippet for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/add-transact-sql-snippets?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Not to mention, your solution doesn't schema qualify, so you won't ever be able to get data from an object that's not on your default schema.